# How well does the Nintendo Switch perform in terms of graphics compared to the Xbox One and PlayStation 4?

Tags: nintendo-switch, performance, hogwarts-legacy

I'm interested in playing *Hogwarts Legacy* on Nintendo Switch.

Since the Switch is a mobile console, I'm a little concerned the game's graphics might not be as good as on the Xbox or PlayStation even when I play it in TV mode.

I tried to find some detailed specs such as resolution but couldn't find them.

Comment: The Switch version of Hogwarts Legacy hasn't been released yet, so this question is technically off-topic. However, since it's more about the Nintendo Switch's performance compared to the Xbox and PlayStation, I decided to remove the focus on Hogwarts Legacy (in the title and tags) to make it on topic. If you disagree with my edit, feel free to roll it back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Nintendo Switch is clearly less powerful than either the Xbox One or PS4. While it was released 4 years later, it is still significantly smaller and draws significantly less power than either home console. It *is* a mobile console, after all.

There are also plenty of benchmarks, reviews, and comparisons that highlight this very fact, such as [Tom's Guide](https://www.tomsguide.com/us/nintendo-switch-vs-ps4-vs-xbox-one,review-4136.html):

> The Xbox One and PS4 are capable of much higher graphics fidelity, both packing powerful AMD Radeon graphics cards and 8GB of RAM (the Switch reportedly has 4GB).

[GameSpot](https://www.gamespot.com/gallery/console-gpu-power-compared-ranking-systems-by-flop/2900-1334/):

> The Switch is Nintendo's only console to date that offers **a teraFLOP** of performance. [...]
>
> Released a few days after the PlayStation 4 on November 22, 2013, Microsoft's Xbox One uses an AMD Radeon graphics solution clocked at 853MHz that offers **1.31 teraFLOPS**, which means it offers 310 more gigaFLOPS than the Switch that launched after it. [...]
>
> Despite garnering a top three spot, the PlayStation 4 is actually the first console to break through the one teraFLOP barrier with its **1.843 offering**. [...]

Emphasis mine.

and also this YouTube video from Digital Foundry comparing The Witcher 3 on Switch and PS4:

From the video we can clearly see how blurry the Switch version is compared to the PS4. We can also see the game struggling to maintain 30 FPS and even occasionally dropping below 20 FPS (nearly dropping to 10 FPS in handheld mode). To put things in perspective, here's a comparison between the Xbox One and the PS4, also by Digital Foundry:

While the performance is comparable to the Nintendo Switch (all consoles struggle to maintain 30 FPS), it's worth noting that they do so at a higher resolution than the Switch. For the Nintendo Switch, according to [Polygon](https://www.polygon.com/2019/10/15/20915391/witcher-nintendo-switch-runs-performance-framerate-resolution):

> To ensure Witcher 3’s playability, the developers dramatically decreased the resolution, dropping it to 540p when in handheld mode, and **720p when docked**. In practical terms, this makes the Switch version look noticeably fuzzier than its counterparts on PC, PS4, and Xbox One.

as for the Xbox One and PS4, according to [ExtremeTech](https://www.extremetech.com/gaming/206070-the-witcher-3-cant-maintain-30fps-on-either-the-ps4-or-xbox-one):

> As you may remember, **the PS4 version runs at 1080p**, but **the Xbox One uses dynamic resolution scaling to switch between 900p and 1080p** depending on how graphically intensive the scene is.

Naturally, the Xbox Series X/S and PS5 are *even more powerful* than that.

Comment: Yes, this is the answer I wanted to know, and I specifically wondered about Hogwarts Legacy. But this game was not released for Switch, so it is not answerable yet. Thank you for the great explanation.